# Regarding QGIS Connectivity To Oracle

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms

I installed QGIS long term release today first 64 bit and second 32 bit. My problem is that SQL Developer for Oracle a non QGIS product does connect to Oracle and when I use the same credentials in both the 64 bit then 32 both cannot connect to Oracle. I did visit this link at  http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/. which supposedly has a download with Oracle dependencies that QGIS needs. It was still installing but is the correct approach. What is the most likely reason QGIS is not connecting to the Oracle database that my SQL Developer for Oracle easily does on the same workstation?

Comment: Do you get any error message ? If so, what is it ?